# Problem with date (react-datepicker) when i paste new date in datepicker input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

[image]

Above screen - initial state date.

But when i copy new date i try paste into input date

[image]

I get the wrong format that I inserted.

[image]

[image]

I should get format 'dd.MM.yyyy' but I get 'MM.dd.yyyy'.

code

```
const onChangeRawDate = (value: any) => {
const isChangeSymbol: boolean = !!value.includes('.');

if (isChangeSymbol) {
  setIsChangeSymbolsOnDateInput(true);
} else {
  setIsChangeSymbolsOnDateInput(false);
}

console.log('datepicker2', value);
```

};

```
<DatePicker
          locale='ru'
          className="date"
          onChange={(date) => {
            handleDate(date, setDate);

            console.log('datepicker', date);
          }}
          onChangeRaw={(event) => onChangeRawDate(event.target.value)}
          selected={date}
          dateFormat={
            isChangeSymbolsOnDateInput ? 'dd.MM.yyyy' : 'dd/MM/yyyy'
          }
          disabled={!isActiveFieldFromSingleParcelOrSinglePickupData}
        />
```

This bug reproduce when i try paste.

Answer (score 0):

Use capital letter. It might help

```
<DatePicker
      locale='ru'
      className="date"
      onChange={(date) => {
        handleDate(date, setDate);

        console.log('datepicker', date);
      }}
      onChangeRaw={(event) => onChangeRawDate(event.target.value)}
      selected={date}
      dateFormat={
        isChangeSymbolsOnDateInput ? ''DD.MM.YYYY'' : 'DD/MM/YYYY'
      }
      disabled={!isActiveFieldFromSingleParcelOrSinglePickupData}
    />
```

Comment: Not working :( ' Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` (in `dd/MM/YYYY`) for formatting years to the input'